# Distinct Match Pair - Teradata/SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to join 2 tables to find match pairs in them, (please see the image for example)

With my join conditions

```
table1 
left join (or inner join)
table2 
on table1.metric1 = table2.metric1
and table1.metric2 = table2.metric2
and table1.metric3 = table2.metric3
```

Result set I get is

```
A 1 , A 2, B 1, B 2
```

Desired result set--- because I want unique pairs from both the table I am trying to get

```
A 1 , B 2 as my final result set.
```

Could some one help me achieve that?
I tried Rank, Partition by but nothing works.
Thanks,

```
table 1         
ID  Metric1 Metric 2    Metric 3
A   x        y           z
B   x        y           z
C   p        q           r





table 2         
ID  MEtric1     Metric2 Metric3
1   x            y        z
2   x            y        z
3   l            m        n
```

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. So because `A` already pair with `1`, mean `A` and `1` can't pair with anyone else?

Comment: HI Juan - Yes, thats correct. I want unique combinations of IDs from both the tables.

Comment: Have you tried a `GROUP BY` clause? Looking at your sample data, the actual results you're seeing look correct to me.

Comment: I am new to the forum, so I am not allowed to post an image. Thanks,

Comment: A 1 and A 2 have the same Metrics, so they will match unless you use a `GROUP BY` clause, even then, you might run into trouble

Comment: Kevin - can you give me an example. I tried doing a group by on Table2.ID however, its expecting me to add all non aggregate columns in the group by, I will have to end up adding ID1 and Metric1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the correct result for your example data:

```
select *
from 
 (
   select t.*,
      row_number()
      over (partition by metric1, metric2, metric3
            order by ID) as rn1
   from table1 as t
 ) as t1
join
 (
   select t.*,
      row_number()
      over (partition by metric1, metric2, metric3
            order by ID) as rn2
   from table2 as t
 ) as t2
 on t1.metric1 = t2.metric1
and t1.metric2 = t2.metric2
and t1.metric3 = t2.metric3
and t1.rn1     = t2.rn2
```

Comment: Dnoeth - thanks, I tried this ranking and joining on rank. However; it doesn;t work for the entire data set which contains more records than what I have in sample, so when i do a rank on table 2, it messes up the rank numbers because table2 might contain more combinations of metric1,2,3 so the order by changes the sequence based on data and hence the rank 1= rank 2 doesn't seem to return all the records. Thanks

Comment: @MIT if that doesn't work try provide a bigger sample. I just create dnoeth  sample in postgresql fiddle and works ok. [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2a886/2). Maybe you could add more data there.

Comment: I tried adding more data to the schema and it's returning the correct result, may be I can try Dnoeth's logic right away and update the forum .. this helps a lot! Thank you, all.